Rails, Rspec, Devise: View Specs with routes within authenticated block

Rails 7
Devise
CanCanCan

How do you work on this point?
On an application I wanted to put all my routes inside the authenticated block, for example:
devise_scope :user do

  unauthenticated do
    root 'sessions#new'
  end

  authenticated do
    ... routes here
  end

end

Resons:

This is like a second umbrella to protect routes from unauthenticated access.
I would not have to write an extra test for each route for the not logged in case.

On the controller/request specs, everything works fine. Because you log_in (Devise Helper) at the beginning of the test.
Problem
On view specs, this throws No route matches for every link_to because on view specs you cannot use the Devise log_in helper. You would have to mock the authenticated block.
From my point of view, I would like to use the authenticated block, but it seems that this is not possible in practice.
How do you work on that point?
How to mock the authenticated block?

The core of the issue here is really that the Rails router is a peice of Rack middleware and  relies on the incoming request to evaluate constraints. In a view spec there is no request and it just relies on feeding the router and view context a faked request. Since the request is not going though the middleware stack Warden will not work.  While you could certainly mock the authenticated method that Devise adds to the route mapper it would be a lot easier and give better acuity to your test to write a feature or system spec that actually drives the whole system.

PS. The helper that Devise provides for integration/system tests is called sign_in.

"This is like a second umbrella to protect routes from unauthenticated access.". That's not a good way to use this feature and its not something you should need if you take a secure by default approach. Your app shouldn't be returning 404 responses when the user is requesting a route that requires authentication.

routes are for routing, not for authentication and/or authorization, just declare before_action with authentication in application controller and skip it for some routes

Found my answer
The Devise authenticated block is not useful in practice, because:
When an unauthenticated user wants to access a specific page of the application, you normally want to cache the request url, redirect him to the login page, and after successful login, redirect him to the original url.
But this is not possible if the route does not exist for unauthenticated.
